# How to confine a jQuery effect to within a specific page section?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a hover-triggered effect active on multiple page sections each with the .slide-trigger class as below, how can I limit the effect to the section that's being hovered over right now?

I have the following code, at present hovering over one trigger div applies the effect to all .slide sections.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slide-trigger').hover(function() {
        $('.slide').addClass('slide-active');
      },
      function() {
        $('.slide').removeClass('slide-active');
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="slide-trigger">
  <div class="slide">
    <p>Slidey stuff</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slide-trigger">
  <div class="slide">
    <p>More slidey stuff</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thankyou!

Comment: Try `$(this)` instead of `$(selector)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your selector to adjust the current element being hovered on event change. You can adjust this by changing `$("slide-active")` to `$(this)`

JQuery `$(this)` will focus on the current element being actioned upon during an event.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slide-trigger').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('slide-active');
      },
      function() {
        $(this).removeClass('slide-active');
      });
  });
});
```

```css
.slide-active {
color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-trigger">
  <div class="slide">
    <p>Slidey stuff</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slide-trigger">
  <div class="slide">
    <p>More slidey stuff</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` keyword in your callback will refer to the element that triggered the event, so you can use it to only apply the effect to that element's children.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slide-trigger').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.slide').addClass('slide-active');
      },
      function() {
         $(this).find('.slide').removeClass('slide-active');
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Amazing! This worked perfectly. I needed to find the .slide within the trigger so I could apply multiple classes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try narrowing the scope to the `.slide` element within the triggered event.  It can be done by finding children `.slide` of `$(this)` element:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slide-trigger').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.slide').addClass('slide-active');
      },
      function() {
        $(this).find('.slide').removeClass('slide-active');
      });
  });
});
```

```css
.slide-trigger {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  clear: both;
  height: 2em;
}

.slide-active {
  position: absolute;
  clear:both;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  transition:1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  100% {
    right: 100px;
  }
}

@keyframes slide {
  100% {
    left: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-trigger">
  <div class="slide">
    <p>Slidey stuff</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slide-trigger">
  <div class="slide">
    <p>More slidey stuff</p>
  </div>
</div>
```